# User with full control getting Access Denied message on Information management policy settings

Tags: 2013, permissions, information-management

I'm completely stumped.  The user has full control of the site (not the site collection, a subsite under a site collection) and on the specific list where he wants to apply information management policies.  That permission is applied directly in both places and through a group in both places.

But, when he attempts to access the information management policy settings page, he gets an access denied message.  Anyone have any ideas why that might happen?  I thought you only needed manage lists in order to change IRM policies for a list.

Comment: Full Control should be enough. The required level is Design, which Full Control includes. Do you get any specific in ULS logs during Access Denied? I had one issue once but the problem was down the line with access to the IRM server for the app pool.

Comment: I'll have to check with our admins when the guy comes in tomorrow morning.  We were wondering if the issue might be related to a lack of access to some library where system pages are stored.  Or that Hidden Taxonomy List.